# Cmd+Enter to open link in new tab not working

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, osx-yosemite

I am using Chrome on Mac OS Yosemite and occasionally when in Chrome, the <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut to open a link in a new tab just stops working. Is there anyway to check the keyboard shortcuts in chrome/reset everything. I've tried to reset all settings, to no avail.

Just FYI - <kbd>Command</kbd>+`Click` works, and <kbd>Enter</kbd> alone opens the link.

Comment: This is a recent issue described here:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=451060

Comment: Thanks for that link, flow3d. This has been driving me insane.

Answer (score 1):

you can press the middle scroll mouse button on the link or 'Cmd' + click the link